# How can you specify a custom error message in rails model validation when a regex is not met?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

Say we have a User model with a name attribute. Let's say we have the following applying to name in our model...

```
VALID_NAME_REGEX = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ _-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/
validates :name, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_NAME_REGEX },
                  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, length: { minimum: 2, maximum: 20 }
```

If the user enters something that is not an alphanumeric, space, underscore, or hyphen, the name will fail regex validation, and the user will not save.

The user will be returned the message "Name is invalid".

This is not very helpful. How can tie a custom message into the regex validation failure, so that if the name fails the regex, we return a custom error like "Name can only include letters, numbers, spaces, underscores, and hyphens"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add "message" key to your validation hash. [Check out the docs.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#format)

```
VALID_NAME_REGEX = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ _-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/
validates :name, presence: true, format: {
    with: VALID_NAME_REGEX,
    message: "Name can only include letters, numbers, spaces, underscores, and hyphens" 
  },
  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
  length: { minimum: 2, maximum: 20 }
```